# Spyder will not launch

Tags: python, spyder

For some reason Spyder is not launching when I try to start the application. I tried to then run it through the console, but run into this error:

```
    (base) C:\>spyder
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
   sys.exit(main())
 File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 233, in main
  from spyder.app import mainwindow
 File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 42, in <module>
  requirements.check_qt()
 File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 44, in check_qt
  import qtpy
 File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 216, in <module>
  raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
  qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I've tried running

```
   pip3 install pyqt5
```

but I get the same error after this installation is completed when I try to launch Spyder through the console. Any advice on this issue?

Can also mention that I tried to download PySide, but couldn't complete the installation as some other errors appeared.

Comment: Run `pip install pyqt5-tools` from cmd.

Comment: Get this error: spyder 5.1.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, but you have pyqt5 5.15.4 which is incompatible.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) By installing PyQt5 with pip you broke your Anaconda installation and now you have to reinstall it. Please [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to learn how to appropriately do that.

Comment: Is there no other way than reinstalling anaconda?

Comment: may I ask why you have to use spyder? I had the same problem and switched to visual studio code. I found out it has many advantages compared to spyder.

Comment: Which advantages did you see?